# Pygame won’t go fullscreen twice

Tags: python, pygame, fullscreen

I know that Pygame has issues with fullscreen but maybe there is a way to fix this:

```
import pygame


class Game:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.fullscreen = False

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.event()
            self.draw()

    def event(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_F11:
                self.fullscreen = not self.fullscreen
                self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
                    (self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height()),
                    pygame.FULLSCREEN if self.fullscreen else pygame.RESIZABLE,
                )

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill("black")
        pygame.display.flip()


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500), pygame.RESIZABLE)
    game = Game(screen)
    game.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I declared an attribute `fullscreen` in the `Game` class. The problem is that it only works once. After pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> again it is as if display mode was set not to be resizable.

Comment: The full screen behavior is system related (and buggy). Does [`pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen) help?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks but that is more buggy than before.